# Why does `while let Some(variable) = ...` not reassign `variable`?

Tags: loops, rust

I am trying to crawl up a path in a loop until a certain condition on the path is met. It seemed like an efficient way to do this would be to use a `while let` loop reassigning the loop variable to its [parent](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.parent) on each loop.

```rust
let path = std::path::Path::new("/my/long/path/to/a/file.txt");
while let Some(path) = path.parent() {
    println!("{:?}", path);
    
    if path_matches_condition(&path) {
        println!("{:?} path matched", path);
        break;
    }
}
```

However, this results in an infinite loop because `path` is not reassigned in the loop statement.

I would have expected the `while let Some(path) = path.parent()` statement to reassign `path` each time, but this does not occur, and the `path` of `path.parent()` does not change.
i.e. The output of the program above would be `"/my/long/path/to/a"` repeated until the program is manually terminated.

This can be remedied by separating the two variables and manually reassigning it inside the loop.

```rust
let mut path = std::path::Path::new("/my/long/path/to/a/file.txt");
while let Some(parent) = path.parent() {
    println!("{:?}", path);
    
    if path_matches_condition(&path) {
        println!("{:?} path matched", path);
        break;
    }

    path = parent;
}
```

Is this happening because, although the `path` of `path.parent()` and the `path` of `let Some(path)` have the same name, they are separated by scope? Could you elaborate on my misunderstanding? Is there a more idiomatic way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, the `path` in `Some(path)` is shadowing the outer `path`.

Comment: BTW, I would probably do something like `path.ancestors().any(path_matches_condition)` instead of your while loop.

Comment: @PitaJ, great suggestion. In my actual use case I need the first ancestor that matches the condition so I don't think the `path.ancestors` approach will workk as smoothly. I'm not sure if the order of `ancestors` is ensured, and if there is a good way to break out of the iteration after the first match. If you have suggestion, I welcome another answer.

Comment: In that case, `path.ancestors().find(path_matches_condition)` will return the first ancestor that matches the criteria. From the docs for that method it seems pretty clear that it starts from `path` and iterates backwards: `path.parent()`, `path.parent().parent()`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The salient difference between what you did and what [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/while_let.html) has is that you are, indeed, never re-assigning `path` - but I think you misunderstand where it doesn't get reassigned.

This statement:

```
let path = ...
while let Some(p) = path.parent() { ... }
```

Takes `path` and calls `parent()`. The `p` in `Some(p)` is not the same variable as `path`. In your code, when you put `Some(path)` you're shadowing the outer scoped `path` variable. But that shadow goes away once the first loop ends, and you've not actually re-assigned the `path` value, so `path.parent()` returns the same value as before.

Therefore, you probably want this:

```
let path = (...)
let parent_path = path.parent()
while let Some(p) = parent_path { 
    ... 
    parent_path = p.parent();
}
```

Note the shadowing occurs because the `let Some(p) = path.parent()` is doing a destructuring. Much like with a match statement - consider this code:

```
fn main() {
    let path: Option<&str> = Some("A path");
    match path {
        Some(path: &str) => println!("{:#?}", path),
        None => println!("Nuthin!")
    }
    println!("{:#?}", path);
}
```

This compiles cleanly, but we can clearly see that the first `path` is an `Option`, while the inner one is a `&str`. The output is:

```
"A path"
Some(
    "A path",
)
```

Comment: "But that shadow goes away once the loop ends, meaning you never really get the parent." What? His second example clearly shows that all you need to do is eliminate the shadowing (bind to a different name within the `Some`) for it to work fine.

Comment: @PitaJ Clarified the sentence. And yes, all the OP has to do is eliminate the shadowing, though it's clear the OP isn't sure of the mechanism that causes this to be true.